# How can I perform array calculations with Vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have been reading and in many places, vectors have been recommended over Arrays, but I am still not understanding completely, and I am not sure if they can work on my project.

I am doing CFD calculations and I have to make some calculations like the following,

```
for(int i = 1 ; i < M ; i++) {
    for(int j = 1 ; j < N ; j++) {
        for(int k = 0 ; k < 4 ; k++) {
            dU_dX_plus=(U[i+1][j+1][k]+dU_dT[i+1][j+1][k]*dt/2+U[i+1][j][k]+dU_dT[i+1][j][k]*dt/2-2*U_p[i][j][k])/dx;
            dU_dX_min=-(U[i][j+1][k]+dU_dT[i][j+1][k]*dt/2+U[i][j][k]+dU_dT[i][j][k]*dt/2-2*U_p[i][j][k])/dx;
            dU_dX[i][j][k]=Wfunct(dU_dX_plus, dU_dX_min);

            dU_dY_plus=(U[i+1][j+1][k]+dU_dT[i+1][j+1][k]*dt/2+U[i][j+1][k]+dU_dT[i][j+1][k]*dt/2-2*U_p[i][j][k])/dy;
            dU_dY_min=-(U[i][j][k]+dU_dT[i][j][k]*dt/2+U[i+1][j][k]+dU_dT[i+1][j][k]*dt/2-2*U_p[i][j][k])/dy;
            dU_dY[i][j][k]=Wfunct(dU_dY_plus, dU_dY_min);
        }
    }
}
```

Can I implement it with vectors? If so, how can I do it? 
Is it worth it or should I keep working with arrays?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `vector` has the advantage, that memory is allocated directly on the heap. This means that you can also use quite large arrays. This is especially important for 3D arrays. Remember: an array of floats with size 100x100x100 takes 4MB memory - too much for the stack in most cases.

By using a `vector` instead of a fixed-sized array, you can also implement arrays with dynamic size, i.e. not fixed at runtime.

You can do it like this:

```
struct Array3D {

    int N, M, K; // size of array

    std::vector<float> U; // storage

    Array3D(unsigned n, unsigned m, unsigned k)
    : N(n), M(m), K(k), U(n*m*k) {}

    float index(unsigned i, unsigned j, unsigned k) const {
        return (i*M + j)*K + k;
    }

    float operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j, unsigned k) const {
        return U[index(i,j,k)];
    }

    float& operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j, unsigned k) {
        return U[index(i,j,k)];
    }
};

Array3D U(6,7,8);
U(1,2,3) = U(2,3,4) + U(2,3,2);
```

Personally I think `U(i+1,j+1,k)` is more readable and writable than `U[i+1][j+1][k]`.

You can also use [boost::multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5f55%5f0/libs/multi%5farray/doc/user.html).

Comment: Very nice answer! Maybe it's worth mentioning `std::array` also.

Comment: `std::array` is 1-dimensional and placed on the stack. For 3D arrays I would strongly recommend using heap storage, e.g. `std::vector`.

Comment: Hmm, if `N,M,K` are well known values beforehand, `std::array` would work pretty much the same. But I see your point about possibly wasting stack memory space.

Comment: `std::array` and raw arrays can be on the heap: `new std::array<int, 1000000>`, `new int[1000000]`. Heap allocation is not the advantage of `std::vector`.

Comment: @bames53: That's right, but using `new` with `std::array` somehow defeats its purpose...

Comment: @Danvil I don't think so. The purpose of `std::array` is to wrap a raw array and make it behave sanely: prevent it from forgetting its type/size and make it act like a proper value type (make it assignable, etc.). Those things are still worthwhile for arrays on the heap.

Comment: @bames53: So you would prefer `new std::array<int,N>` over `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: @Danvil Usually `std::vector` is the better choice, but it does have overhead associated with the fact that its size is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` is nothing more than a wrapper around a heap allocated array and the array's size. You can do most anything with a vector that you can do with a heap allocated array.

`std::vector` is typically recommending over raw c++ arrays for two reasons:

1. because `std::vector` is type safe. Raw arrays forget that they are arrays and forget their size very easily, which can lead to invalid memory accesses.
2. because `std::vector` manages the lifetime of the heap allocated array rather than requiring you to use `new[]` and `delete[]` manually, which is error prone.

---

One disadvantage of `std::vector` is that it's not as convenient to use as a multi-dimentional array.

```
double U[M][N][4];
U[i][j][k];
```

You can flatten a multi-dimentional array into a single dimension:

```
std::vector<double> U(M * N * 4);
U[N*4*i + 4*j + k]
```

Another option would be to write your own typesafe, resource managing class that acts as a multi-dimentional array.

```
class _2d_array {
  std::vector<double> arr;
public:
  const int rows, columns;
  _2d_array(int rows, int columns) : arr(rows * columns), rows(rows), columns(columns) {}

  struct row_proxy {
    _2d_array &arr;
    int row;
    double &operator[] (int column) { return arr.arr[arr.columns*row + column]; }
  };

  row_proxy operator[] (int row) { return row_proxy{*this, row}; }
};

_2d_array U(M, N);
U[i][j] = 10.23;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... `vectors` have been recommended over `arrays`, but I am still not understanding completely, and I am not sure if they can work on my project.

`arrays` are a C++ 11 feature. They are also fixed in size.

`vectors` are readily available. They are dynamic and can change size.

Use whatever works best for your situation. If you need C++03, then you have to use a `vector`. If you need to grow the array, then use a `vector`.

Comment: I think OP means an C-array like `int a[6][7][9]`.

Comment: C-arrays are part of C++. OP tries to evaluate C++ alternatives.